# How do I allow a service account to access a shared drive on Google Drive if it is set to not allow

Tags: google-drive-api

We are creating a program to access Google Drive using a service account.

We have found that the program fails to call the various APIs of Google Drive unless the setting to allow access to the shared drive to accounts outside the company is turned on.

However, I do not want to turn on the setting that allows the shared drive to be accessed by accounts outside the company. I don't want to allow ordinary users to have access to accounts outside the company.

Is there any way to leave this setting off and still allow service accounts to access it?

I checked the internet for a setting to treat the service account as an internal user, but could not find one.

Comment: you can share a folder with the service account and it will have access to that folder,  If this is google workspace you could configure domain wide delegation and it will have access that way.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have tried domain wide delegation. However, it did not work as expected. It seems that even with the delegation settings, it is not possible to ignore the settings for access from outside the company.

Comment: Yes thats true a workspace service account wont have out side the company access.   Can you exit your question and give a bit more detail into your usecase?